# Conditional PHP if recordset results by country

Tags: php

How do I conditionally display text on a PHP page of MySQL results that uses the following syntax to display data already `<?php echo($row_Rep_Locator['Country']); ?>`

In this case, I want to show text "hello world" at the bottom of the page ONLY if the Country is equal to United States for example?

Comment: ehm .. `if ('United States' == $row_Rep_Locator['Country']) {}`

Comment: too localized?  whatever...this question could easily work for any place on the planet or solar system but okay.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco this questions is so simple, it is not even worthy for SO.

Comment: Rene Pot = Douch ...now that is SIMPLE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `switch()`:

```
switch($row_Rep_Locator['Country']){
    case "en_US":{
        echo "Hello America";
        break;
    }
    default:{
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

This solution is especially faster if you want to check many different conditions, usually at about 3 if clauses.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if ($row_Rep_Locator['Country'] == "United States"){
    echo 'hello world';
}
?>
```

You might want to consider doing some basic PHP tutorials

Comment: Why would I want to do that when I can interact with such brilliant, positive, inspiring people such as yourself?